How did people know that the war against the mimics was over?
During the majority of the Edge of Tomorrow (2014), Cage resets to about 24 hours prior to his killing of an Alpha - which occurred in the middle/afternoon of the day of Earth's offensive attack.  This means on his death he always resets to the period just after he was railroaded into combat.  (But after one incident, Cage loses his reset ability).
Eventually Cage and Vrataski realize that the only way to save the attack is to kill the Omega prior to the attack occurring, so they all pile into a drop ship and head to Paris during the night before the attack.  Cage ends up killing the Omega, gets doused with the Omega's blood and resets once again.
Cage again resets to about 24 hours previous.  But as he killed the Omega in the hours before the attack, he resets to the period prior to him being railroaded, when the helicopter is landing in England.
And this is where it gets confusing.  While Cage has reset to this time period, his killing of the Omega won't happen for about another 24 hours. But as his helicopter is landing, he hears all the church bells ringing and finds out that the war is over.
So how are people celebrating when the action that causes the celebration to occur has yet to happen?

And please, no mention of "timey-wimey".  I detest that phrase even though I have watched DW from the very beginning, and even think that David Tennant was a great Dr.

There were a whole lot of comments on this post containing general discussion about time travel and related concepts in fiction. It was interesting but not particularly relevant to this specific question, so I've moved those comments to chat. Please feel free to continue general discussion in the linked chatroom, while keeping comments here relevant to the specific question being asked about Edge of Tomorrow.

When Cage kills the Omega near the end of the film, we see a pulse of some sort spread outwards from the Louvre, with all the other Mimics collapsing in its wake.





This lines up with what Dr. Carter told Cage about the Mimics being parts of a single organism; the Omega was like the brain and its death seemingly killed them all.

CARTER: Right. Well, first of all... you're not fighting an army. You have to think of this as a single organism. Now, these common drones, they act like its claws.
VRATASKI: And Alphas, like the one that you killed, are much more rare.
[...]
CARTER: They're like its central nervous system. But this... is the brain. It controls them all.




After waking up in the past for the final time, Cage watches a news broadcast on television in which General Brigham explains that a large surge of energy was detected in Paris just before sunrise, resulting in a total collapse of the Mimics' capacity to fight.

BRIGHAM: Just before sunrise this morning, a large surge of energy was detected in Paris. We do not know exactly what this signifies. But the result appears to be a total collapse of the enemy's capacity to fight. Russian and Chinese troops are now moving across Europe without resistance. Tomorrow, we advance on the western front. We believe we are marching to claim victory for ourselves... for our loved ones... for our countrymen... for the entire human race.




Logically, the United Defense Force couldn't have known anything about Cage killing the Omega in the (now-alternate) future. It's not clear that they even believed in the Omega's existence. All they knew for sure is that, just before sunrise, there was a mysterious energy surge in Paris, and that since then, all apparent resistance from the Mimics had fallen away. They hadn't yet confirmed that the war was over, but they'd seen enough to be cautiously optimistic that victory was imminent, leading to some degree of celebration.
What exactly happened just before sunrise wasn't strictly spelled out, but given the similarity between what Brigham described on the news and what we saw for ourselves when the Omega died, I believe the filmmakers intended us to make a connection there and surmise that the Omega's death in the (alternate) future somehow killed it in the past as well. There's no other explanation I can see for why the Mimics would have abruptly lost their capacity to fight.
Also, it doesn't make sense for Cage to look as happy and relieved as he does when the film ends, if he thinks the Omega is still alive. After all, not only would it mean that he'd need to go kill it again in order to truly end the war in humanity's favour, but he'd likely have fumbled his best opportunity to do so, since he barely managed to kill it before when it didn't know he was coming, and now it would know he's coming.

GRIFF: You heard what Cage said. Do not kill an Alpha. If we kill an Alpha, the Omega will reset this whole day. We'll never even remember we had this conversation. And they're gonna know we're coming.


So fundamentally you're saying that the Omega is connected with itself in the past (by 24 hours), and that its death in the future also kills it 24 hours in its past.  But that also has issues (with the movie).  If there is no lag in Cage resetting when he dies, there would still have to be a lag between the Omega (and all other mimics) dying, and people noticing that they are dead (especially as the attack hand't yet occurred), and hence the church bells couldn't have started chiming until well after the helicopter landed.

The only way for it to work is if there is some sort of delay when Cage resets.  One that would allow the Russian and Chinese troops to realize that there is no longer any resistance.  To verify that fact, communicate it with the rest of the world, and have the authorities instantly release that information.  But bureaucracy never works that fast.

@PeterM what if the Omega’s death in the future kills it 26 hours in the past.

The only way for it to work is if there is some sort of delay when Cage resets.
It could also be that he resets back to 24 hours prior, and 24 hours prior to a night-time raid cage was sleeping. He reset back to being asleep, and we see him wake up sometime after the reset point.

@Peter M - Brigham said the energy surge occurred just before sunrise. The Sun is clearly up by the time we see Cage in the helicopter with the bells ringing, suggesting that time was reset not to the point that he woke up, but to some time earlier. We don't know how much time passed between the surge and him waking up, but when he watches the news broadcast on television, the time at that point is clearly shown on-screen as 08:57. The Sun typically rises around 06:00 in London, give or take half an hour, which suggests that 3-ish hours passed between the energy surge and that news broadcast.

@PaulD.Waite I don't that a measly two hours difference solves the problem.  You couldn't analyze the entire European theater in a couple of hours.  And you need to do that to figure out of the war is really over.

@LogicDictates Can you realistically survey all of Europe in 3 hours to ensure that the war is actually over?

@Peter M - Probably not, but Brigham never said the war was over. He said that the enemy appeared to have lost their capacity to fight and that they believed they were marching toward victory. If they were still marching toward victory, it follows that they hadn't yet declared victory.

@PeterM: how about 200 hours

@PaulD.Waite And a reset time of 200 hours then would conflict with everything that has previously been laid out in the movie.

@PeterM: I didn't say a reset time, I said killing the Omega. Could they not be different? (I only saw the movie one a long time ago, so I might be forgetting details that mean they can't be different.)

@PeterM: To add to what LogicDictates mentioned, they had seen a large surge of energy in Paris, and then the enemies they could see were immediately unable to fight, as I understand it; they didn't need to survey the entire European theatre, the theatre they had seen seemed to indicate that every enemy unit stopped functioning, that they could see, and timed with the energy surge, they're noticing that they seemed to be aligned.

Taking at the face value the quote:

CARTER: Right. Well, first of all... you're not fighting an army. You
have to think of this as a single organism. Now, these common drones,
they act like its claws.
VRATASKI: And Alphas, like the one that you killed, are much more
rare.
[...]
CARTER: They're like its central nervous system. But this... is the
brain. It controls them all.

then logically, that "24h reset" is a reaction of Omega to the death of an Alpha. Cage hijacked Alpha's function when got doused with it's "blood", and took it's place in the "nervous system", meaning he did NOT kill that Alpha before hijacking it.
Extrapolating that to Omega - that is: assuming Cage became Omega before it died - it's possible that Omega goes back either 24 hours in time automatically, as a defense mechanism or it picks the "destination".
The obvious question at this point is: Is Carter the new Omega, just the  "targeting-device" or just Cage? The three hour discrepancy between Cage's reset and Paris surge suggests Omega can choose the restore point, and both Cage and Omega chose different ones.
So, from my point of view, what happened was that Cage killed Omega somewhere between the time it triggered that 24 h reset and actually going back to "restore point", and the resulting

large surge of energy (..) detected in Paris

was Omega's hardware shorting out, carried over with the reset, quite possibly overloading the Omega at it's restore point by that double-restore.
And people cheer because - as it says in the news:

Russian and Chinese troops are now moving across Europe without
resistance

as an assumed result of that "surge".
